# Pass variable into Primefaces selector

Tags: jquery, jsf, jquery-selectors, primefaces

In my JSF/Primefaces page I have a form containing a tabview, where each tab contains an accordion panel, and each accordion contains a data table. The full id of the single data table is something like `id="form:tabs:0:accordion:0:table"`

Each tab contains also a command button that must update data tables inside the tab itself, so it would not update tables inside the other tabs.

Using Primefaces Selectors, I managed to update all the data tables which id finishes with "table": `update="searchValue @('div$=table')`, but I am not able to address all the data tables which id finished with "0:table", where "0" is dynamic (based on the current tab).

I tried with:

```
<ui:param name="ta" value="#{settore.id - 1}:table" />
<p:commandButton id="plainSearch" value="Filter"
    action="#{myBean.search()}"
    update="@('div$=#{ta}')">
```

but it gives me a Javascript error: `Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier`, then the entire form is updated.

How can I correctly pass a variable to a Primefaces selector?

Here is my XHTML page:

```
<h:form id="form">
  <p:tabView id="tabs" value="#{myBean.sectors}" var="tab">
    <p:tab id="tab" title="#{tab.description}">
    <p:commandButton id="plainSearch" value="Filter"
      action="#{myBean.search()}"
      update="@('div$=table')">
      <p:accordionPanel id="accordion" value="#{myBean.getTabs()}" var="tab" multiple="true" activeIndex="#{myBean.activeIndexes}">
        <p:tab id="accordionTab" title="#{tab.title}">
          <p:dataTable id="table" var="row" value="#{myBean.getObjects()}"  emptyMessage="Empty table">
            <p:column headerText="Code">
              <h:outputText value="#{row.codice}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Description">
              <h:outputText value="#{row.descrizione}" />
            </p:column>
          </p:dataTable>
        </p:tab>
      </p:accordionPanel>
    </p:tab>
  </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I am currently using a workaround: each table has a style class defined as `styleClass="#{tab.id - 1}_tableStyle"`, and the command button refers them with `update="@(.#{settore.id - 1}_tableStyle)"`.

Comment: Are you looking for the right primefaces/jquery selector or for a way to put in the number of the tab with EL? What happens if you set the '0' manually like `update="@('div$=0\:table')"`? Does it work then?

Comment: @Jens, I am looking for a way to put in the number of the tab. But I noted (with Firebug) that I always obtain the following error: `SyntaxError: missing } after property list ... updateSelector:'@('div$=table')'});return false`, even using `update="@('div$=0\:table')"` or `update="@('div$=table')"`.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about the (jquery) selector itself. If I understand it correctly primefaces is using jquery selectors at this point and the syntax of @() will just identify this as a jquery selector.

If it is a jquery selector ([Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)) shouldn't it be like this:

```
$(div[id$=table])
```

and for the version with the id:

```
$(div[id$=#{ta}\\:table])
```

**EDIT :** I have updated the code examples (without quotes)

Comment: Using `update="@('div[id$=\"table\"]')"` I obtain the error `Invalid location of text (\"]')") in tag (<p:commandButton>).`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an example running to test this. I guess you need to find a way to let all necessary characters appear in the final html (i.e. escaping special chars). Sorry, I don't have a chance to test this currently.

Comment: I guess you can't use single quotes. `update="@(div[id$=table])"` does not produce an error. It seems that you can even leave out the double quotes on the table.

Comment: Without single quotes I obtain the error `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div$=table`.